# Incorporating taggable person names into a database

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, database-schema

First time posting, first time working with relational databases, so be gentle!

Working on a database of relevant fiction novels, and I'm running into some difficulty with persons of responsibility, such as author or illustrator or preface-writer.

I thought to store the persons in a 'persons' table, with first_name and last_name, but when a user enters a new book to the database, I want the persons of responsibility to act almost like tags, with an autocompleted list appearing as well as allowing them to enter a new author... in a single field, not two.

Further, each person will have a role tied specifically to that book in question. Is there anything terribly wrong with a table 'book-person-role' with 'book_id', 'person_id', and 'role_id'? Or should I separate this into two tables, 'book-person' and 'person-role,' with this 'person-role' table linking to the primary id of the 'book-person' table?

Answer (score 0):

First the second question:

> Further, each person will have a role tied specifically to that book in question. Is there anything terribly wrong with a table 'book-person-role' with 'book_id', 'person_id', and 'role_id'?

If you have only one role_id connected to book_id and person_id you can use one table. Joining tables is slow and generally the fewer the tables you have the faster it works (if everything else does not change). In this particular case the number of rows is not increased. So there is nothing wrong with having one table, and you even have a bonus: it works faster.

Concerning the first question. If you have a many to one relationship of books to persons you should use different tables for books and persons. And you can do the user interface whatever you like. You can join tables, make several requests. You did not say what programming languages you are using so I cannot help you write the code for the user interface you want.

EDIT:
The way you proposed to make persons table (first_name and last_name as different fields) is a good way. When you want to lookup a person you make an AJAX call to server the server uses OR and returns the list. For example, you want to find a name in #name_input input tag.

HTML:

```
<input id="name_input" type='text' />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('keydown','#name_input',function(){
    var jqxhr = $.ajax( "name_lookup.php?name="+$("#name_input").val())
      .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert( "add data to your lookup list" );
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
      })
});
```

PHP:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
if ($result = $mysqli->query(
  "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM persons WHERE first_name = $name OR last_name = $name ORDER BY last_name"
)) {
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: Oy, I'm sorry. Sometimes I'm a little bit dense.

I'm writing in PHP with mySQL. I know to have a pivot table for relating authors to books... I'm mostly concerned with how I can store the author data, primarily the names, to allow for alphabetical sorting via last name as well as a single input field for the user.